# Mac AppStore Resume Issue

Tags: mac-appstore, resume

I'm using Mac App Store on Lion, But there is a problem with download resume. After every system restart I can't resume my previous downloads and I have to download them from the beginning, I also checked and I have no AppStore directory at this path ~/Library/Application Support/
AppStore store the temp files at a directory in 
/private/var/folders/s1/ ... /com.apple.appstore/
But after restarting the computer and opening the AppStore it deletes all the contents of this directory, and I have to start the downloads all over again.
I also tried restarting AppStore in debug mode but it didn't work.
I'm wondering if someone have a solution for this issue.

Regards

Comment: Have you considered letting the download complete?

Comment: How much HD space is available?

Comment: @bmike If I let it it will be completed, But my connection bandwidth is low so I want to be able to resume downloads later.

Comment: @orange There is 16GB available.

Comment: The system will attempt to resume the download if it have confidence in the package - nothing was corrupted and the disconnect was clean. Something is changing - perhaps on the server end to prevent that nice resume from happening. You may not be able to control this, sadly.

Comment: @bmike I'm sure that is not the case because since I updated my computer to Lion, I couldn't resume any downloads after system restart.

Comment: @TRI try freeing up some more space. Make sure there's a minimum of 20% free disk space.

Comment: @bmike That's not the case my computer storing previously downloaded data even after system restart, but instantly deleting them when I open Mac AppStore.